# Unable to send date field from sendKeys to ion-datetime field in Javascript Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, ionic-framework, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a test case for my ionic project. I am trying to send a date value to my date field but I am unable to send date value to my `<ion-datetime>` field.

I have tried the following code. But it throws `element not interactable` error.

```js
await driver.findElement(By.name('dob')).sendKeys('2020-12-12');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Ionic datetime component github page for the full component documentation :
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/tree/master/core/src/components/datetime

Check the availables Properties, here you need `value` :

```
var datetimeElem = document.getElementById('dob');
datetimeElem.value = '2020-12-12';
```

Comment: There is no id is provided in `<ion-datetime>` tag so I have used `getElementByName`

Comment: Add your own id : `<ion-datetime id="yourId">`, or as your id seems to be "dob" : `<ion-datetime id="dob">`